# What client architecture for an LCD wall application?

Tags: flash, html, video

I have been asked to design an LCD wall application for [a display like the one in this ad](http://elport.en.ec21.com/TFT_LCD_Wall_Dz_Wall--155370_155376.html).

Requirements are that the wall can display full screen video or partition the wall in different sections to display multiple video or images and video.

I would like to understand what platform can be used to drive such beasts (what OS? what video card?).

I wonder what software platform can drive multimedia on such a scale. Html5 + JavaScript would be OK on a single monitor, but on that scale would it slow down? Flash also is an interesting platform, as it is Air, but, once again, can it scale like that?

I am also considering the server architecture that is needed to drive a set of walls in the same location and the slideshow designer to create storyboards, but this is dependent on what client architecture will be embraced.

Thank you for any orientation.

Comment: on second inspection it looks like the LCD wall I have linked has a 1024x768 display which would be no problem to handle, but still one could consider a smaller solution with four monitors in square, that would make a possibile virtual screen size of somewhere around 2000x4000.

Comment: what is your largest number of monitors?

Comment: I think that 2x2 could be a good comprimise for starting the business. Maybe an upper limit could be 4x4.

Answer (score 0):

[Matrox](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/) has an interesting line of video cards that may suite your needs.  I myself have been researching them for similar projects.  Specifically, check out the M-Series and G-series cards.

The graphics card will do most of the work.  The 'server' will only need to be capable of playing your video at the overall resolution.